# How to validate input text fields like phone number, numeric fields and email validation using typescript in ionic 3?

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I'm trying develop an ionic 3 android application. Now i need to validate input fields using typescript only not javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these links:

- [MDN - Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)
- [HTML5 Form Validation Example](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)
- [Angular Guide:Form Validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#built-in-validators)
- [Angular Validators API](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators)

```css
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid email address">
```

Comment: Since all code in Typescript gets transcompiled to Javascript anyway, the need for Typescript only is somewhat of a moot point. Check out.  http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: Thank ypu for quick replying.. I did fix the problem from your code.. Thank you much..

Comment: @BenSweet - Would you like to mark answer as correct then?